# How to convert this string to Luxon Datetime object (Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, luxon

I have the following Javascript/Typescript code to convert a string to a Luxon DateTime:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';    
const x = '2023-10-27T01:00:57.830+00:00'
const y = DateTime.fromFormat(x, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log('y = ', y)
```

This produces the following output:

```
  y =  DateTime {
    ts: 1698282057830,
    _zone: SystemZone {},
    loc: Locale {
      locale: 'en-US',
      numberingSystem: null,
      outputCalendar: null,
      intl: 'en-US',
      weekdaysCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
      monthsCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
      meridiemCache: null,
      eraCache: {},
      specifiedLocale: null,
      fastNumbersCached: null
    },
    invalid: Invalid {
      reason: 'unparsable',
      explanation: `the input "2023-10-27T01:00:57.830+00:00" can't be parsed as format yyyy-MM-dd`
    },
    weekData: null,
    c: null,
    o: null,
    isLuxonDateTime: true
  }
```

How to properly convert this object?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fromISO` method.

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

const x = '2023-10-27T01:00:57.830+00:00';
const y = DateTime.fromISO(x);
```